# How to parse instructions in assembly into binary(MIPS)?

Tags: parsing, file-io, mips

I'm trying to do a MIPS project for Comp Arch where I have a text file with a bunch of random mips instructions and I have to do what MARS does and translate these instructions into binary and write the result into a new file.

What I've thought of so far:
-I know how to read a file and write to one
-I think I'll need to hard code the registers binary values and the instructions op codes and function codes

My question is how do I parse through the file and read the instructions to figure out which binary pieces to put? Like if it was add $t1, $t2, $t1 I want it to read "add" and jump to a loop that has the op code and function for add then keep going and if it reads $t1 to pick up the binary value for t1 and so forth until it finishes the line and then have a cue to jump to the next line and keep going.

Any advice on how to parse the file or tips for the project in general are welcome. I probably did a bad job of explaining it but basically we are trying to create what mars does but on a much smaller scale with a select few instructions and registers

Comment: This depends on the programming language and libraries that you use, which you haven't specified in your question. What you've described sounds pretty basic, so I suggest that you start by read the documentation for whatever language/libraries that you're using.

Comment: I'm using Mars simulator with MIPS assembly language. That was in my question unless you mean something else?

Comment: Write proper code to build an assembler, compile and execute.